# Can't insert intro/full article image

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, administrator, images

For some strange reason I cannot insert intro/full article image in articles anymore.

1. On "Images and Links" tab, I click on button to add images.
2. Popup screen appears and then I paste image url in "Paste image URL in textarea, you can press Enter to add a line, one line per image" textarea.
3. I click the Insert button and nothing happens

In Firebug Console I noticed that clicking the Insert button gives a javascript error:

**"ReferenceError: insertFormField is not defined"**

There's no reference to a js file that triggers the error. Any ideas?

PS. my joomla installation is up to date (version 3.6) and there were no new extensions installed.

**-------------UPDATE--------------------------------------------------**

Please take a look of this link in official Joomla demo website:

https://j390p102.demojoomla.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&asset=com_content&author=&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&folder=

**The same link on my website gives me a blank page... Any ideas??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have either some files corrupted on update, or some outdated server software.

1. Overwrite your web-site with Joomla 3.6.0 full package to be sure it's no a file corruption (extract the Joomla full package and upload everything except installation folder using overwrite).
2. If this doesn't help, enable development error level and check the link. You'll see the problem. Search in Global configuration -> Server tab.
3. Depending on the problem - we can suggest what to do.
4. Don't forget to switch error level back to System or None on the production server.

Comment: It turned out that my website had been hacked. Several core files were changed. I replaced them all with a fresh downloaded joomla pack, and problem was fixed. Thank you for your help

Comment: Alas, that's not enough. If it had been hacked, the hacker definitely placed some backdoor new files. So replacing doesn't remove the hacker files. Besides, even if cleaned up, you must determine the reason why it was hacked. Usually it's a vulnerable non-updated extension. Can be a virus-stolen password from an FTP manager at a windows machine. 
I use a Moskalian tool for cleaning up which scans your web-site for suspicious files https://www.revisium.com/ai/

If you just have overwritten your hacked web-site with the core joomla files, you will be hacked(you are now) again in a while.